# Как определить, из какой версии servlet-api вызывает getDispatcherType() в jsp?

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat

В dependencies в pom.xml для javax.servlet.api на Tomcat 8.0.22 задана версия 3.1.0 эта библиотека лежит в Maven Dependencies.

При генерации JSP происходит ошибка:

```
 The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest
```

Однако, в Maven Dependencies есть и версия servlet.api.2.5, которая является зависимостью для одной из библиотек.

Как определить, какая версия servlet.api вызывается, jsp генерируется с ошибкой? И, если вызывается неправильная версия, как показать Maven, что нужно вызывать правильную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос:
Достаточно много способов выяснить версию использованного api.
Самый простой использовать метод интерфейса 
[ServletContext.getMinorVersion()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMinorVersion())
и
[ServletContext.getMagorVersion()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMajorVersion())

Касательно последней части вопроса:Maven не коим образом не курирует разворачивание приложения все условия такого типа описываются дискрипторе развертывания web.xml
По вашему вопросу для определения версии использованного обратите внимание на xml тег    `<web-app...>`

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, эти методы нужно использовать в самом JSP. Но сгенерированный JSP падает вот на этом месте:

`if (!"GET".equals(_jspx_method) && !"POST".equals(_jspx_method) && !"HEAD".equals(_jspx_method) && !javax.servlet.DispatcherType.ERROR.equals(request.getDispatcherType())) {
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, "JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD");
return;
}`
И я вижу пустую страницу. Т.е. status 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Нет эти методы можно использовать везде где доступен Context...Далее не забудьте о web.xml где версия  описана так-же

Comment: Оказалось, что используется версия 2.5, вместо 3.1.0.  Во всех POM'ах прописана правильная версия и в проекте даже не применяется функционал, использующий версию 2.5. Собственно, удалением этого кода проблема и решилась. Но теперь мне непонятна причина вознакновения проблемы.

Comment: Понятно.А касательно первопричины здесь уже вариантов масса Начиная от последовательности разработки проекта,настройки шаблона или архетипа который Вы использовали настройки Каталины ...магия в конце концов...С той стороны виднее )